# ¿ Como aumento el tamaño de las imágenes?

Tags: css, bootstrap, imagen

Estoy tratando de aumentar el tamaño de los círculos con las imágenes y soy incapaz sin que me rompa otras partes de la pagina. Imagino que sera sencillo.
Dejo muestra de lo conseguido hasta ahora.
Gracias.

> NOTA: EDITO EL CODIGO DE LA PREGUNTA, para ver si pueden ayudarme. Editada con enlaces a bootstrap.

```css
/*style custon*/
   body {
padding-top: 50px;
color: #959595;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
color: black;
}

.feature {
background-color: yellowgreen;
color: greenyellow;
}

.article-intro {
margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.footer-blurb {
padding: 30px 0;
background-color: goldenrod;
color: black;
}

.footer-blurb-item {
padding: 30px;
}
 
.small-print {
background-color: #fff;
padding: 30px 0;
}

.feature,
.page-intro,
.article-intro,
.footer-blurb,
.small-print {
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh‌​4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Corporate 1a</title>

</head>

<body>
 
 <footer>
  <div class="footer-blurb">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 footer-blurb-item">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://i66.tinypic.com/280intx.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100">
      <h3>prueba</h3>
      <p>Probando.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Procrastinate</a></p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 footer-blurb-item">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://i64.tinypic.com/fjes6w.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100">
      <h3>Prueba</h3>
      <p>Probando </p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Unleash</a></p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 footer-blurb-item">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/1044421.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100">
      <h3>prueba</h3>
      <p></p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">OTRA</a></p>
     </div>
    </div> 
   </div>
        </div>  
 </footer> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Es bastante dificil de responder viendo solo esa parte de codigo sin que expliques mejor que es lo que se "rompe", para aumentar el tamaño de los circulos tenes que aumentar el tamaño de las imagenes ponele a alguna width y height 200 para probarlo.

Comment: Miguel a que te refieres con "sin que me rompa otras partes de la pagina" ?

Comment: @Camilo Vazquez, pues que no funciona como me lo puso el compañero Santiago Roldan, ya lo probe yo. Quiza deberia a ver puesto mas codigo, pues hay otros estilos que impiden que la imagen se haga mas pequeña. Quiza deba editar la pregunta...???

Comment: Entonces editala lo más completa que puedas y miramos que pasa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pues con solo un `width` y un `height` se logra hacer mas grande y no veo que se rompa nada.

```css
/*style custon*/
   body {
padding-top: 50px;
color: #959595;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
color: black;
}

.feature {
background-color: yellowgreen;
color: greenyellow;
}

.article-intro {
margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.footer-blurb {
padding: 30px 0;
background-color: goldenrod;
color: black;
}

.footer-blurb-item {
padding: 30px;
}
 
.small-print {
background-color: #fff;
padding: 30px 0;
}

.feature,
.page-intro,
.article-intro,
.footer-blurb,
.small-print {
text-align: center;
}

.img-circle{
  border-radius:50%;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh‌​4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Corporate 1a</title>

</head>

<body>
 
 <footer>
  <div class="footer-blurb">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 footer-blurb-item">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://i66.tinypic.com/280intx.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100">
      <h3>prueba</h3>
      <p>Probando.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Procrastinate</a></p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 footer-blurb-item">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://i64.tinypic.com/fjes6w.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100">
      <h3>Prueba</h3>
      <p>Probando </p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Unleash</a></p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 footer-blurb-item">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/1044421.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100">
      <h3>prueba</h3>
      <p></p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">OTRA</a></p>
     </div>
    </div> 
   </div>
        </div>  
 </footer> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: gracias @Santiago Roldan pero eso ya probe y no me funciona, quiza deberia editar la pregunta para incluir mas codigo y ver que lo impide. ¿ Que te parece?

Comment: @MiguelEspeso me parece bien ya que si no podemos ver cuando rompe, no te responderemos de manera indicada

Comment: Ya edite @Santiago Roldan

Comment: @MiguelEspeso es solo esa linea amarilla?

Comment: Y unas pocas de lineas de css, @Santiago Roldan, he dejado sin poner otras pocas. Gracias

Comment: @MiguelEspeso si las otras linea que no pusiste son insignificantes dejame decirte que a mi me sigue funcionando bien sin dañar nada

Comment: Pues no se, ami ahora no aumenta de tamaño, es lo unico, @Santiago Roldan

Comment: @MiguelEspeso edite la respuesta poniendole todos los estilos y sigue funcionando igual, fijate que no te falte informarme de algo mas.

Comment: Prueba ahora, que edite añadiendo los enlaces a Bootstrap v3.3.5 , gracias @Santiago Roldan

Comment: @MiguelEspeso Listo, me sigue funcionando igualmente, ya edite el codigo

Comment: Compañero @Santiago Roman, tenia usted razon, funciona, me faltaban las imagenes en mi archivo, lo hice :<img class="img-circle" src="images/caminos.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200">

Comment: @MiguelEspeso Me alegra que te haya funcionado, que te termine de ir muy bien con tu pagina. cuidate!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes Probar con un **transform: scale(3);** donde se encuentra el numero 3 puedes colocarle la escala que quieras.

```css
        .img-circle {
        border-radius: 50%;
        transform: scale(3);
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   
    <title>Corporate 1a</title>

</head>

<body>
 
 <footer>
  <div class="footer-blurb">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 footer-blurb-item">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://i66.tinypic.com/280intx.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100">
      <h3>prueba</h3>
      <p>Probando.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Procrastinate</a></p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 footer-blurb-item">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://i64.tinypic.com/fjes6w.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100">
      <h3>Prueba</h3>
      <p>Probando </p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Unleash</a></p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 footer-blurb-item">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/1044421.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100">
      <h3>prueba</h3>
      <p></p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">OTRA</a></p>
     </div>
    </div> 
   </div>
        </div>  
 </footer> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Voy a editar la pregunta para poner mas codigo, gracias

Comment: Tampoco funciona con  transform: scale(3); @ijar